Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll getting this exception
In StoryTelling.cs Modal File:
I have written this Model to save the file Id's submitted by the users, tried adding exceptions but all I'm getting was that exception is there anything wrong with Model or controller I'm getting confused here
 getting this exception
namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class StoryTelling
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        public string PreferredName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Indigenous status is required. Please enter 'Yes' or 'No'.")]
        [RegularExpression("^(Yes|No)$", ErrorMessage = "Indigenous status must be either 'Yes' or 'No'.")]
        public string Indigenous { get; set; } = "No"; // Default value is "No"

        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstNationIdentity { get; set; }

        [Url]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Agreement { get; set; } = false;

        [Required]
        public bool Acknowledge { get; set; } = false;

        public DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsApproved { get; set; } = false;

        // Navigation property for related GoogleDriveFiles
        public List<GoogleDriveFile> GoogleDriveFileIDs { get; set; }
    }

    public class GoogleDriveFile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FileId { get; set; }
        // Other properties as needed
    }
}

in StoryTellingController.cs file:
When Post with Details getting that error Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
   [HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddStoryTelling(StoryTelling story)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    story.SubmissionDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

    _context.StoryTelling.Add(story);

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetStoryTellingById), new { id = story.Id }, story);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        // Log the exception details
        Console.WriteLine($"DbUpdateException occurred: {ex.Message}");

        // Check if there's an inner exception
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException.Message}");
        }

        // Return a generic error message
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Error occurred while saving data to the database.");
    }
}


All the info you need is in the exception. You need to log it correctly and/or debug and check the message. Please provide the exception message - without it it will be hard to help.
